# How to post array value fron input name

Tags: php, arrays, post

i want to pass an array value from input name that generated from an array. i can view $_POST if i manually define on script.

```
   $stmt    = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {

        $id=strtoupper($row["id"]);
        $nama=strtoupper($row["nama"]);
        $sn=strtoupper($row["sn"]);
        $kewpa=strtoupper($row["kewpa"]);?>



        <form method="post" action="kewpaupdate.php"><tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="id[<?php echo $i;?>]" value=<?php echo $id;?>></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="kewpa[<?php echo $i;?>]" value=<?php echo $kewpa;?>></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>

        </tr></form>
        <?php ++$i;
    ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>

<?php

$w = $_POST['id'];
$r = $_POST['kewpa'];

echo $w;
echo "<br>";
echo $r;
?>
```

how to display array value that choose from submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1) As you are printing the `$_POST`ed data on the page itself, you need to submit the form to same page.

Please change `<form>` action to blank.

Changed form action code:

`<form method="post" action="">`

This will submit the form to same page.

2) As your input has `name` of type `array`, you can't just print it with [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or [print()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php).

These are used for printing `string`s.

You need to use [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

So, please use:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['id']);
echo '<pre>';
```

You will get an array, same for the other field.